# GitHub issues asked on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464614/why-wont-my-css-file-show-for-my-github-page

Do questions about the usage of [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) fit in the Stack Overflow paradigm?

Comment: No, they don't; see e.g. [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Comment: Well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/github

Comment: @jonrsharpe That would apply if this was a question like, "my GitHub account was hacked, how do I get it back" or something, but for questions about normal usage of the site I would expect it to fall under a tool used for programming, and be on topic.

Comment: @Servy I suppose it depends whether the problem is caused by GitHub itself (i.e. a bug in their software) or just the OP's usage of it, which I don't know enough to determine.

Comment: I could see this as on-topic, as this relates more to the OP's usage of the platform (creating a GitHub Page with some custom styling) as opposed to it being a bug in their software.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't know enough to tell the difference either, but the first type of questions don't belong here, and the latter do.  The same is true of any other tool one is using while programming.  As to which this question is, I leave it to those active in that tag to determine.

Comment: @Mysticial not all questions in existing tags (even those that *don't* say they're off-topic *cough* [tag:appstore-approval]) are on-topic!

Comment: @jonrsharpe True, but it *is* a strong indication, and should at least give you some idea as to what's going on.  The number of questions, and the percentage of closed questions, give further tells.

Comment: @Servy fair point

Comment: So because it has to do with usage and not an actual bug (that is what it seems) this does fit within the paradigm?

Comment: It does sometimes depend on whether the question is about github pages or actually applicable to all of CSS (making it on topic here), with this question I would say it is too vague to know if it is a github problem or a more general problem

Comment: @Mysticial the interesting thing about the github tag is that all the open questions talk more generally about git as a whole and work on any git tool. I think that's why that contradiction exists

Comment: Of the 6 most upvoted questions on SO, half of them are about GitHub.

Comment: @Servy github is not a [tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_tool), it is a [service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)

Comment: would-be-duplicate question on SE is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225897/are-questions-about-github-on-topic-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**Yes**

Quote from the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> ## What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers;** and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

I believe GitHub *does* fit into the highlighted sentence as well as an IDE or a VCS (and these tools are widely a widely accepted topic here)

---

Obviously there are catchas, in the same way as asking questions about IDEs or other tools: if you found a bug only the developers may be able to answer your question, but it's not something unique to GitHub.

Comment: github is not a [tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_tool), it is a [service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service)

Comment: @n611x007 Your comment is irrelevant since the sentence says *software tools* and **not** *programming tools*.  A software tool *need not* be programming related. I don't think that the fact that it is primarily used through a webbrowser doesn't changes anything.

Comment: @n611x007: And a *service* is a *tool* maintained and executed on someone else's machine.

Answer (score 26):

Yes.

In fact, this question was not closed because it was about Github; it was closed because the OP did not provide what we needed to reproduce the issue *in the question itself*.

Even the close reason says that:

> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close
>   gave this specific reason:
>
> "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?")
>   must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error *and the
>   shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*.
>   Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
>   readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
>   example."

If the OP would provide a simple number of steps to reproduce, plus only the code needed to reproduce the issue in the question, it would not be closed right now.

Comment: Note that this Meta question was asked 21 hours ago, and the Main question was only closed 5 hours ago. So probably OP wasn't talking about the Main question's current state.

Comment: clarify 'yes'. talking about the irrelevant example is irrelevant.